# Disable click on an element during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to prevent clicking on an element, while it performs some animations and then enable it later. I have tried to use unbind and then bind, but clicking remains permanently disabled.
Is there any other way to do it?

```
$("something").on("click", function() {
    $("selected").unbind("click");
    $("selected").animate({...}, function() {
        $("selected").unbind("click");
    });
```

basically, i don't want someone to click on the selected div while the animation is in progress, as clicking on it will start another set of animations which i don't want to start in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using a flag variable to store the info if the animation is happening:

```
var animating = false;
$("something").on("click", function () {
    animating = true;
    $("selected").animate({...
    }, 1000, function () {
        animating = false;
    });
});
$("selected").click(function(){
    if (animating) return false;
});
```

Comment: while this will work it doesn't remove the eventhandlers from the selector and it makes the code less readable. better use on() and off(). Well that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use on and off this way you can "bind" the function foo to a click event on a particular element, switch it off and on again, as many times as you like. Have fun ;-)

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4yBbb/2/

```
var foo = function() {
// Code to handle some kind of event
};
// ... Now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$( "p" ).on( "click", foo );
// ... Foo will no longer be called.
$( "p" ).off( "click", foo );
```

edit: updated answer, my example used delegation and this was not necessary.

applied to your example it would look like this:

```
$("something").on("click", function() {
    $("selected").off( "click", foo );
    $("selected").animate({...}, function() {
        $("selected").on( "click", foo );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on() & .off() event of jquery. here is the example [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

you need to do somthing like as follows:

```
function flash() {
  // do your stuff here
}  
$("something").on("click", function() {
    $( "body" ).off( "click", "Your Div Selector", flash );
});
$("something").on("click", function() {
    $( "body" ).on( "click", "Your Div Selector", flash );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> clicking remains permanently disabled.

Because when never bind the `"click"` again to `$("something")`. Try:

```
$("something").on("click", function animate() {
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.off("click");
    $("selected").animate({...}, function() {
        _this.on("click",animate);
    });
```

Here I use named function to make it easy to refer to the function again.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a check in your `click` function to perform the animation only when the clicked element is not animating?

```
$("something").on("click", function() {
    $("selected").animate({...});
});

$("selected").on("click",function(){
    if(!$(this).is("selected:animated")){
    //Start other animation
    }
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/c9CnA/)**